# how to convert this C++ code to Turbo C?

Tags: c++, turbo-c

C++ code:

```
cout << "Roots are complex and different."  << endl;
cout << "x1 = " << realPart << "+" << imaginaryPart << "i" << endl;
cout << "x2 = " << realPart << "-" << imaginaryPart << "i" << endl;
```

How can I convert this to Turbo C like `printf` instead of `cout`?

Comment: "because of reasons" -- what reasons?

Comment: I have to convert it to #include <stdio.h> #include <conio.h>, I have to use printf("\n\n\t\t "); instead of cout, i wanted to ask how?

Comment: @manetsus: I used printf("\n\t\t " x1 = (( realPart "+" (( imaginaryPart (( "i" ))))))); but the error is "function call missing )", I did something but srsly I don't know what I was doing -_-'

Comment: @porsche.h read the documentation for `printf()` before using it.

Comment: printf("\n\n\t\t "x1 = " << realPart << "+" << imaginaryPart << "i" <<);
printf("\n\n\t\t "x2 = " << realPart << "-" << imaginaryPart << "i" <<);

I tried to compile and run the program but the errors are:
Function call missing )
Unterminated string or character constant
Statement missing ;

how? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are seeking for this:

```
printf("Roots are complex and different.\n");
printf("x1 = %lf+%lfi\n",realPart,imaginaryPart);
printf("x2 = %lf-%lfi\n",realPart,imaginaryPart);
```

if `realPart` and `imaginaryPart` variables are in data type `double`.

Use `%f` for `float`, `%d` for `int`, `%s` for `string` instead of `%lf` in the code otherwise.

Comment: realPart = -b/(2*a);
       imaginaryPart = sqrt(-determinant)/(2*a);
       printf("\nt\t Roots are complex and different.");
       printf("\nt\t x1 = %lf+%lfi", realPart, imaginaryPart");
       printf("\nt\t x1 = %lf+%lfi", realPart, imaginaryPart");

Comment: there's still an error, I wanted to show you my whole program :3

Comment: "\nt\t " -- It is extra thing that you are adding (may be it is your need). but the above code does not have this. @porsche.h

Comment: yeah, but "\n\t\t is for spacing only, it does not affect the codes right? lol, sorry. and thank you for the patience

Comment: Yes, I'm new, some of my friends told me that this website is helpful, yeah sorry, Im not a programmer seriously, Civil is far from any programming based course but I have to pass this program for my final project, I'm still learning how this site works, so yeah. I just dont get why my program won't run -_-