# C++ Programming error codes

Tags: turbo-c++

```
printf("\n\n\t\t x1 = " realPart "+" imaginaryPart "i" );
printf("\n\n\t\t x2 = " realPart "-" imaginaryPart "i" );
```

I tried to compile and run the program and the erros is `Function call missing )`
what's the correct code? Thank you! :)
ps. I tried to put another `)` at the end, it gave me more errors :3

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achive. Input? Output? Please add some words about your **actual problem**! Thanks :-)

Comment: Im trying to compile so I could run the program but can't because of the error. My programs is all about solving the quadratic equation to find its roots :3 Thank you! :)

Comment: You should really add some code you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `printf` correctly. See the code below. I am assuming your variables are `float` type.

Also, given that you are using `C++`, you need to include `<cstdio>`.

```
printf("\n\n\t\t x1 = %f+%fi",realPart,imaginaryPart);
printf("\n\n\t\t x2 = %f-%fi",realPart,imaginaryPart);
```

Comment: ...but it's confusing that `x1` and `x2` are based on the same variables.

Comment: @Wolf it's possible that OP is trying to print the complex number and its conjugate.

Comment: @Wolf Actually, you are correct. It is unclear what OP is asking, as the answer to their [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32664533/4330447) seems to also answer this one...

Comment: I tried it, the programs doesnt have any errors now but it doesnt show the output.

Comment: @porsche.h The call to `printf` will show the output. If it is not showing output, that means your program didn't get to the point where the call to `printf` happened. Perhaps you have some `return` statement before it, or perhaps the `printf` call is in an `if` statement that evaluated to `false`, or perhaps the call to `printf` is in a loop where `break` happened before it or where the condition of the loop never is `true`.

Comment: Oh gods, srsly. I'm not good with this. Could I grab your email so i could show you my whole codes? I'm CE not and SE student, so I found it hard tho. Sorry :3

Comment: @porsche.h you better added it to you question. Depending on your operating system and your IDE, it may be hard to *see* any console output. Did you ever get a hello-world program executed on your platform that behaved as expected?

Comment: @tchen good to see your answer accepted (as it was really helping a bit)! I didn't expect that :-)